# Error Creating a mex file in Matlab 2013 using Matlab codegen

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-deployment, matlab-coder

I have a function named test (test.m) which I want to convert to mex file using codegen in Matlab 2013b.
here B is a structure containing a  zero matrix p_z (  size 128 * 128 ) and plastset is a empty matrix ( 0*0 ). 
I am getting an error converting the following code:
Unless 'rows' is specified, inputs must be vectors. For variable-size inputs, either the first or second dimension must have a constant length of 1 , for the line
'actset = setxor ( actset , plastset );' in the below mentioned code

Please help me rectify the code for successfully creating the below function into a mex file.

```
function [] = test(B)

p_z = B.p_z;

plastset = B.plastset;

if isempty(B.plastset)
     plastset = zeros(1,0);
end


if isempty(find( p_z > 0, 1 ))
     actset = zeros(1,0);
else
     actset = find( p_z > 0 );
     actset = setxor ( actset , plastset );
end
```

Comment: I lack codegen, but the documentation hints that you must specify the types of the parameters via the -args switch. [http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/19303-what-does-this-error-message-mean-no-class-precondition-specified-for-input-x-of-function-squa](mathworks support thread).

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like setxor does not support matrices for the way you are calling it. If you want to do setxor for all the elements in actset with plastset, try to make them as a vector using colon operation.

```
actset = setxor(actset(:), plastset(:));
```

Comment: Thank you I shall try this out n let u know